# Python Manual/Isolated/Portable Windows Installation

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, installation, pip

I thought it is an easy question but I spent a lot of google time to find the answer with no luck. Hope you can help me.

My company has a large SW system on **windows** which is **portable**, meaning copy some folders, add some folder to windows path and you are ready to go.

No registry, no dll in system directory, no shortcuts, Nothing!

I want to start using **python 3.x** in our system in the **same paradigm**. I also want the ability to add to this distribution a  pip/conda **3rd packages** from time to time.

- I **don't want** to install python msi on all the systems.
- I **don't want** to pack it to standalone executable like py2exe and pyinstaller or use special python distribution like PyWin32.

Somehow, I couldn't find a formal official solution for that.

The closest thing was [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html) but **no pip is supported**, python is **minimal**, and the system isolation is **"almost"**.

> 3.8. Embedded Distribution New in version 3.5.
>
> The embedded distribution is a ZIP file containing a minimal Python
>   environment. It is intended for acting as part of another application,
>   rather than being directly accessed by end-users.
>
> When extracted, the embedded distribution is (**almost**) fully isolated
>   from the user’s system, including environment variables, system
>   registry settings, and installed packages. The standard library is
>   included as pre-compiled and optimized .pyc files in a ZIP, and
>   python3.dll, python36.dll, python.exe and pythonw.exe are all
>   provided. Tcl/tk (including all dependants, such as Idle), pip and the
>   Python documentation are not included.
>
> Note The embedded distribution does not include the Microsoft C
>   Runtime and it is the responsibility of the application installer to
>   provide this. The runtime may have already been installed on a user’s
>   system previously or automatically via Windows Update, and can be
>   detected by finding ucrtbase.dll in the system directory. Third-party
>   packages should be installed by the application installer alongside
>   the embedded distribution. Using pip to manage dependencies as for a
>   regular Python installation i**s not supported** with this distribution,
>   though with some care it may be possible to include and use pip for
>   automatic updates. In general, third-party packages should be treated
>   as part of the application (“vendoring”) so that the developer can
>   ensure compatibility with newer versions before providing updates to
>   users.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

How about... installing Python in one machine and replicate that installation on others computers?

Usually, I install Python in a Windows Virtualbox machine (Microsoft usually give it for free to try it or for testing old Internet Explorer versions).

Then I copy the Python directory to my Windows machine (the real host) and usually works. This makes possible to using various python versions.

Did you try to complete the Python Embedded Distribution? Usually they not come with Tkinter, but once I could copy files and put in this distribution in a way that works. Try it too.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and follow the guideline 

there to provide quality answer.

Comment: @thewaywewere from your [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) what exactly I didn't do? (asking for learning...)

Answer (score -1):

You can [install pip with get-pip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py)

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question